# how to stop div wrap in two colomn page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hello Stack overflow community. I am just getting better at coding and this is probably my first of many questions. I cant post images till I reach 10 rep so the image representation of what i need is in the link below.

https://6ff6bf8640d4ef91208a73a6d9d14f00ce70afa0.googledrive.com/host/0B667ouzaQ0tXbGQ5RXJFaHI2NlU/Stack%20Question%201.png

I have created a div class="tile". and a mobile html page with two columns. Each "tile" div has a image"img" and a button"a href". I want them to wrap as tiles and not cut in half the way they are in the image. Here is my simplified code:

```
<hmtl>

<body>

<div class="2 columns">

<div class="tile">
<h3 ><img class="tileimg " src="anyimage"></h3>
<button>More</button>
</div>


<div class="tile">
<h3 ><img class="tileimg " src="anyimage"></h3>
<button>More</button>
</div>

</body>


</html>

<style>
.2 column{    
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;}
</style>
```

The tile gets split into two part but i just want them to stick together. I am using HTML. CSS. Javacrpt and Jquery and Jquery mobile.1.4.5 Trying to create a mobile web based app.

Can I use JavaScript to force them to stick together? whatever you guys think is the best solution. I've been searching all over the web. and Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS. It tells to do its best not to break inside the tile so both elements stock together. Found at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/

```
.tile{
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
    break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set `display:inline-block` for `.columns`

Answer (score 0):

You can use table to put them side by side as in your image...

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<div class="tile"> 
<h3 ><img></h3> 
<button>More</button> 
</div> 
</td> 
<td> 
<div class="tile"> 
<h3 ><img></h3> 
<button>More</button>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: inline-block;` to the tiles.

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile">...</div>
    <div class="tile">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

&

```
.tiles {
    column-count: 2;
    ...
}
.tile {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Columns work essentially by automatically wrapping on whatever line of flow content they deem necessary. By telling them the tiles are `inline-block` (i.e. inline elements), you're basically saying that the whole tile is like a "letter" or a "word" - a single unbreakable item on a "line" of flow content.

---

On a sidenote, your classes in HTML and CSS don't match. I'd advise against using just numbers and instead suggest using either something like `class="columns columns-2"`, or (better) using semantic markup like `class="tiles"`.